# can't compare datetime.datetime to int ; datetime to unix  timestamp

Tags: python

I am trying to write a basic program that iterates through files in a directory and checks for files modified in last xxxxxx. Unfortunatley datetime does not allow me to iterate to an int.

```
file_list_attr = sftp.listdir_attr('/Path')

for f in file_list_attr:
    print "name=%s, modified date=%s, size=%s" % (f.filename, f.st_mtime,f.st_size)

mt = f.st_mtime
now= dt.datetime.now()
delta = dt.timedelta(minutes=2120) 
while mt > dt.datetime.now() - delta:

#while f.st_mtime == now-dt.timedelta(days=1):
   print 'You have something here'
else:
    print 'nada'
```

Comment: Check/fix your indenting - python is indenting-sensitive (unsure if you intentionally indented that way, or if it's a result of trying to put it on stackoverflow).

Comment: If some of your other questions have been answered, consider going back and marking those answers so people know they've been answered.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are comparing to a unix timestamp (st_mtime), use time.time() and seconds instead of trying to use datetime.  If you really want to use datetime, it has a fromtimestamp method you could use to convert the st_mtime to create something comparable to the datetime.